# error while loading CharSequence in Scala 2.11.4 and sbt 0.12.4

Tags: java, android, linux, scala, sbt

I have an android-scala project which has subprojects in it. In all `build.sbt` files I set the scalaVersion:

`scalaVersion := "2.11.4"`

and in `project/build.properties` I set this:

```
sbt.version=0.12.4
```

However, it keeps generating this (Scala 2.9.2) `/home/alex/Documents/projects/android/my_project//project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes` and it keeps throws an exception when I run sbt by just typing sbt in the root folder:

```
[error] error while loading CharSequence, class file '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1501)
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Yes, I have JDK 8, but I'm using scala `2.11.4`.

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sbt 0.12.x does not support JDK8.  Please migrate to sbt 0.13.x, the latest is 0.13.7

Comment: I get the same error and when I de-install 0.12.4 and install the newest windows version SBT-0.13.8.MSI from "scala-sbt.org/download.html" I again get the same error. Using the 'about' command in sbt shows still version 0.12.4. I de-installed it multiple times, made sure that no other version is installed and that I indeed execute the newly installed version and it still shows 0.12.4. Something is very wrong here ...?

Comment: @jsuereth I got the exact same error - and I use sbt 0.13.5 with JDK8. Any ideas